# ExpressionEngine (CMS) with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, integration, expressionengine

Has anyone out there hacked up ExpressionEngine (CMS) to work with SQLite?  If so, any good tips or guides on how to do so?

Comment: do you mean a **regular** expression engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any Expression Engine 1.6 that has been modified to support SQLite; however, the next version (2.0) is based on the CodeIgniter framework which has a DAL which supports many databases. Here is a [post](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/76104/#379737) from an Ellis Labs employee confirming this.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it's proprietary software under copyright and not available (so far as I can tell) under an F/OSS license, tightly tied to MySQL (*no* other dbs supported and you can't run MySQL in strict mode, meaning they rely on nonstandard extensions) I don't think you're going to find what you are looking for.

Even if someone had done it for their own use it would look an awful lot like a derivative work (though I suppose you could try to claim it was a parody) and distributing it would be a copyright violation.

Why don't you contact the vendor and offer to shell out some $$?  Or look into a F/OSS alternative?  There are (*cough*) several of them out there.

-- MarkusQ

Comment: I'll always use a F/OSS package over a paid one for my own personal use.  This, however, was for a client paying to use EE.