# How to make ExpressionEngine use SQLite

Tags: sqlite, expressionengine

I’m using EE for the first time. I design/develop on two machines, so I use private github repos for all my client work. I’d like to run this EE project on SQLite locally while I’m developing and designing, and then switch it to MySQL once I’m ready to deploy to the staging environment for client review. That way, I can track DB changes easily between machines, as there is a lot of content on this particular site, and exporting/importing DB tables every time I switch machines (three or more times a day) is getting old.

I realize I could use the client’s MySQL DB remotely, but would rather keep everything local, if at all possible. So, how can I run EE with SQLite?

This question (or something similar) was made almost three years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334085/expression-engine-cms-with-sqlite). The accepted answer hints at possible support in EE v2.0+ (via CodeIgniter’s then-new database abstraction), but I can’t find any recent information (official or otherwise) on how to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I short: no. Active Record is not universally-used throughout EE, and especially not in third party add-ons. In fact, the [documentation for the Database class](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/usage/database.html) does not mention Active Record at all.

I'd suggest just installing MySQL locally.

Comment: I _do_ have MySQL installed on both machines, and that’s what I’ve been using without issue. What I’m trying to avoid here is having to export/import the updated DB each time I switch machines. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll have much luck with non-MySQL DBs — MySQL statements are hard-coded into EE, despite the EE 2.0 promises of a fully-fledged CI app with various DB connectors.

I think your best results might be to find a centralized host for your dev DB. EE is especially painful to work with on multiple machines because of the DB — the whole thing is really built with "one server, one developer" as the primary use case.

You can simplify it a bit by keeping your templates saved as files, and rigging your settings to be server-agnostic. I also keep little scripts around to quickly dump/import the DB when I have to, which makes moving the site around in a git repo a little easier. A few details here: http://www.viget.com/inspire/expressionengine-on-multiple-machines/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Doug! I’ll check that article out…